# Breakfast: Across a Software Refactor (5)

Tags: puzzle-creation, cryptic-clues

> A remove button with a cheesesteak (6)
>   Superlative travel with a transfer coed. (8)
>   The concussion from a KO (3)
>   A contemporary speech defect (7)
>   Always bigger there, but smaller (3)

First (and maybe last :) cryptic effort, so I'm putting this under puzzle-creation. Criticism and derision welcome! :)

This should result in 5 answers to the lines and a final answer.

Hint:

> The five lines refer to the names of [programming languages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages).

Comment: Shake (5) button (6) gently (6) lol.

Comment: @nikamed, hey, sometimes that's how you get the older machines working!

Comment: Is the final answer (got by putting together the 5 answers) the same as the answer to the clue in the title?

Comment: @randal'thor, yeah. So, hopefully the type (of the 5) are implied as well.  To further clarify though, the five are needed for the title/final answer.

Comment: I enjoyed this.  To be pedantic, each clue on its own is missing the definition portion, so the hint was mandatory.  Again pedantry, but I'd prefer "A bit of cheesesteak"  to indicate the truncation.

Comment: Yeah, these aren't *quite* cryptic clues. There's no indicator for most of the truncations (which don't quite work because they're not common abbreviations), and none of them have any definition. Still, great start! If you're going to make another, I suggest reading over the precise rules for cryptics. The wordplay here is pretty good - it's just the definitions (both of the wordplay components and the missing ones) that need a bit of work.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore, Yes, it wasn't all of Philly or Philadelphia, so that should be noted. Using a list versus included definitions is a clear crutch, but it shouldn't be an Easter egg hunt to find the list. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: With definitions the clues would indeed have been closer to standard cryptics -- but the puzzle wouldn't have worked at all. So I'm not bothered by the absence of definitions. But I really don't like PHI for "a cheesesteak" or "The concussion from" as an anagram indicator or really anything about the Texas one. (Also, TeX really isn't a programming language, it's a typesetting system that happens to be programmable.)

Comment: (Also also, the letters of "TeX" are not the first three letters of "Texas", they are a Greek tau, epsilon and chi.)

Comment: @Deusovi, Thanks a bunch for the feedback. Heard and noted.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, No one likes 'concussion' it seems. I probably need to stay on the reservation a while. Sounds like I'm hearing, stay away from cultural references (within reason I suppose), be consistent (Title/final puzzle wise?), and know your references (i.e. TeX). Thanks for your notes. Very helpful!

Comment: I don't think "concussion" is all that bad, for what it's worth. Just ... not great :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Look alike letters are perfectly acceptable in cryptics.  I've even seen clues like "#4 odd" for Y.

Comment: And I should state that I'm not bothered by the lack of definitions, as the hint was given.

Comment: yeah, strongly agree that the lack of definitions isn't a problem in this particular puzzle

Comment: +1 for the effort to create several linked clues and a metapuzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A remove button with a cheesesteak (6)

> Delphi  (DEL from delete, PHI from Philly)

Superlative travel with a transfer coed. (8)

> UberCode (Uber - Superlative, also a method of travel. Transfer (anagram) of COED)

The concussion from a KO (3)

> OAK (Anagram of AKO, but I'm not really feeling "The Concussion" as an anagram hint)

A contemporary speech defect (7)

> NewLISP

Always bigger there, but smaller (3)

> TEX or TeX - Things are bigger in Texas.  (But smaller version of the word).

Breakfast: Across a Software Refactor (5)

> Go across the 5 software tools listed, take the first letter.  DOUNT and Refactor into a tasty breakfast treat: DONUT

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the feedback on concussion. You should get the last one fairly soon I'd think.

Comment: Admittedly an underwhelming final answer. But good job.

Comment: Couldn't have done it without the Wiki list.

Comment: I liked transfer Coed and Always Bigger the best.  A good clue should make the solver chuckle or groan when it's solved.  A great clue will make the solver shout "You Glorious Bastard" at the setter.